# Help with simulating a system model (inverted pendulum)

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems

In this documentation article, [Regulate an Inverted Pendulum](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/RegulateAnInvertedPendulum.html), the author started by creating the following system.

```
pendulum = 
  StateSpaceModel[
    {(M + m) x''[t] - m l Sin[θ[t]] θ'[t]^2 + m l Cos[θ[t]] θ''[t] ==  
       F[t] + d[t] Cos[θ[t]], 
     m x''[t] Cos[θ[t]] + m l θ''[t] == m g Sin[θ[t]] + d[t]}, 
    {θ[t], θ'[t], x[t], x'[t]}, 
    {F[t], d[t]}, 
    {θ[t], x[t]}, 
    t] /. {M -> 5.6, m -> 0.53, l -> 0.85, g -> 9.8};

poles = {-1 + 2 I, -1 - 2 I, -5, -7};
```

Then he got the feedback gains

```
k = 
  Join[
    StateFeedbackGains[SystemsModelExtract[pendulum, 1], poles], 
    ConstantArray[0, 4]}]
```

and plotted the output response with `x` and `θ`, keeping `θ` close to zero,  with the following

```
Plot[
  OutputResponse[
    SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[pendulum, k], 
    {0,UnitStep[t] - UnitStep[t - 1]}, 
    {t, 4}] // Evaluate, 
  {t, 0, 4}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
  Epilog -> 
    Inset[Column[{Style["x(t)", 10, Blue], Style["θ(t)", 10, Red]}], {3, 0.004}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t"}]
```

[image: plot]

My question is how to pass the desired position and angle he wants the system to stabilize at; i.e., `x = 1, θ = π/6`

Comment: Is it even possible for this model to stabilize with the pendulum 30° from vertical?

Comment: I believe it is possible to stabilize at 30°, because one of the model inputs is the force `d[t]` applied at right angles to the pendulum.  Expect `d[t]` to swing negative when $\theta$ is positive.  Also, the system model has outputs $\{\theta [t], x[t]\}$ in that order, so the blue curve is $\theta$ and the red one is $x$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Just pass it as the input at the OutputResponse. Instead of {0,UnitStep[t] - UnitStep[t - 1]} pass {0,1}.

Comment: ok, i read the example: "to regulate an inverted pendulum about the upright position", so it should be stabilized at θ = 0 at any time. If you want to stabilize the pendulum at θ = π/6, you can't stabilize the position x=1. You would drive the car with constant speed in one direction (x grows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StateFeedbackGains` solves a regulator problem.

You need to try `AsymptoticOutputTracker` to track a reference trajectory (which are constants in your case).

```
pendulum = AffineStateSpaceModel[{(M + m) x''[t] - 
   m l Sin[θ[t]] θ'[t]^2 + 
   m l Cos[θ[t]] θ''[t] == 
  F[t] + d[t] Cos[θ[t]], 
 m x''[t] Cos[θ[t]] + m l θ''[t] == 
  m g Sin[θ[t]] + d[t]}, {θ[t], θ'[t], x[t], 
 x'[t]}, {F[t], d[t]}, {θ[t], x[t]}, t] /. {M -> 5.6, 
m -> 0.53, l -> 0.85, g -> 9.8};

poles = {-1 + 2 I, -1 - 2 I, -5, -7};
fb = AsymptoticOutputTracker[pendulum, {π/6, 1}, poles];
csys = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[pendulum, fb];

Plot[Evaluate@OutputResponse[csys, {0}, {t, 0, 4}], {t, 0, 4}, 
PlotLegends -> {θ[t], x[t]}]
```

[image]