# OutputResponse and contradictory control models

Tags: plotting, control-systems

So I'm trying to learn some control theory for a little project I'm working on and decided I'd try the examples of pendulum and cart one can find all over the internets, and I'm following [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133298/help-with-simulating-a-system-model-inverted-pendulum) and [this website](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/RegulateAnInvertedPendulum.html) and [this post on the wolfram blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/01/19/stabilized-inverted-pendulum/)

I know the mechanics "relatively" well and I decided to do slightly differently than on those pages and use the Lagrange 2nd form to build my ode like so:

```
xx = x[t];
xy = 0;
px = l Cos[\[Phi][t]] + xx;
py = l Sin[\[Phi][t]] + xy;
params = {m1 -> 1, m2 -> 0.5, l -> 0.85, g -> -9.8};

T1 = 1/2 (m1 (D[xx, t]^2 + D[xy, t]^2)) (*cart*);
T2 = 1/2 (m2 (D[px, t]^2 + D[py, t]^2))(*pend*);
V1 = -m1 g xy (*cart*);
V2 = -m2 g py (*pendulum*);


T = FullSimplify[T1 + T2];
V = FullSimplify[V1 + V2];
L = FullSimplify[T - V] ;

eqn1 = FullSimplify[D[D[L, \[Phi]'[t]], t] - D[L, \[Phi][t]]];
eqn2 = FullSimplify[D[D[L, x'[t]], t] - D[L, x[t]]];

deqns = {eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == f[t]} ;
ics = {\[Phi][0] == (85 \[Pi])/180, \[Phi]'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{{deqns /. params, ics} /. {f[t] -> 0}}, {\[Phi][t], x[t]}, {t, 0, 30}];
pen1 = {l Cos[\[Phi][t]], l Sin[\[Phi][t]]} /. sol /. params
```

With this plot as a result for the pendulum and cart respectively:

```
ParametricPlot[pen1, {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotStyle -> Dashed] Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image: newplot2]

So far everything is fine, Though is is the beginning of my problem, please note I have used **g -> -9.8**  and potential energies also negative to get this to plot correctly.

Afterwards, I have started make the SSM and the TFM like so:

```
model = StateSpaceModel[deqns /. params, {{\[Phi][t], \[Pi]/2}, {\[Phi]'[t], 0}, {x[t], 0}, {x'[t], 0}}, f[t], \[Phi][t], t]

tfmodel = FullSimplify[TransferFunctionModel[model]] /. params
```

[image: tfmodel]

And now things I don't understand anymore:

As you can see in the picture the first component in the denominator is negative. Which, surely breaks causality...

Attempting to Plot the OutputResponse on the homogenous side gives me:

```
Plot[{OutputResponse[tfmodel /. params , UnitStep[1 t], {t, 0, 60}]}, {t, 0, 30}, Evaluated -> True, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image: wrongplot]

Which to me seems completely wrong. But, I carry on to try and create a control scheme regardless:

```
nmodel = model /. params
q = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1000, 10, 1000}];
r = {{1}};
gains = LQRegulatorGains[nmodel, {q, r}];
controlmodel = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[nmodel, gains];
Plot[OutputResponse[{controlmodel, {0, 0, 1, 0}}, {0}, {t, 40}] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, Epilog -> Inset[Column[{Style["x(t)", 10, Blue], Style["\[Theta](t)", 10, Red]}], {3, 0.004}], AxesLabel -> {"t"}]
```

And this as a result:

[image: poor]

Which besides some obvious poor drift, seems like a plausible result...

Until I change in the params, **g -> 9.8**
Here all parts of the TFM are now positive and the final plot looks more like one that is actually under a control scheme, However the parametric plot is now broken, as if gravity is now forcing the pendulum upwards

[image: control]

I must be missing something here, because there are two problems I don't understand,

One: What gives with g? When plotting the curve, One must absolutely have a negative gravity for the pendulum to fall down with, This reflects well in the parametric plot

Two: If this is simply a definition problem...why are my TFM, SSM, and in the end LQR regulator all requiring a different for lack of better word, direction of g?

What exactly am I misunderstanding here? 
Are these plots even correct? Are they only showing the deviation at pi/2 that I defined in the SSM?

A bonus question would be: How do I plot the x-cart like in the linked examples...although I nearly one for one copied the code. I can't get x[t] to plot parallel with phi[t] which would greatly help in determining of the control scheme is doing anything correctly.

[image: xplot]

Thanks in advance for the help!

**edit**
I have updated the initial plot with labels like suggested, the inner red arrow is the initial angle displacement of the simple undampened pendulum, 85pi/180 rads, in mathematical positive direction, the second outer red arrow is the direction I expect the system to fall with a negative gravity...Which it does like expected.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to create a diagram showing what you mean by x, y, and $\theta$. That will probably help you answer your own question. And your `ParametricPlot` is essentially that of a simple pendulum, not an inverted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following changes:

- $g\to 9.8$ in *params*
- $V1= m1 g \ xy$
- $V2= m2 g \ py$

And then finally do

```
Plot[StateResponse[{controlmodel, {0, 0, 1, 0}}, {0}, {t, 40}]//Evaluate, 
{t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabels -> {\[Phi], \[Phi]', x, x'}]
```

to get

[image]

The above (and the result of OutputResponse[tfmodel /. params...]) are the deviations from the equilibrium values. So $\phi$ is now zero at the positive y axis and positive in the counter clockwise direction.

Comment: Hi! thank you for the answer!, however I can't agree with your changes. You're right paraplot IS a simple pendulum, The sys is displaced in math. pos. direction changing that to math. neg. in ics and g to positive will model the inverse system. One that hangs at 3pi/2 that falls upwards and a negative tfm...meaning that a pos. right x movement will result in a pos. right fall from the pendulum..which physically can't happen...http://lizard-truth.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/newp-2.png See here. Atleast thats how I understand my system and your answer, did I misunderstand? My bad if so!

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment above. But  in `ParametricPlot` the y axis in positive upwards, in your convention the y axis is positive downwards. You would be better off plotting $\{l \cos (\phi (t)),-l \sin (\phi (t))\}$.

Comment: Mmm. Plotting like your suggested gives me the inverse system of the plot...I'm confident my y is defined postive...Unless I'm drastically misundestanding how I mechanically defined my system. (could very well be!) http://lizard-truth.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/updown.png the change you suggested plots y in the negative direction. (the orange)..Which is not how my system is defined. The y component in the L vector most certainly should be l*sin[phi[t]]. My apologies If I'm being dumb here or something here....but I can't see how -l is a possibility at all.

Comment: We are probably talking past each other. As per my first suggestion, add a diagram showing the mass and pendulum, and your positive x and y axis, and $\theta$.

Comment: Ah, that could very well be! I updated the post, and here is a direct link of my system. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpQI9.png

Comment: And I have updated my answer accordingly.